# What will happen if a scorpion pierces itself?

Tags: zoology, poison

If a scorpion pierces itself, will it die or immune to its poison? If it produces the venom its blood should be immune to itself poison.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the venom is produced and stored in an isolated venom sac or other container, the rest of the scorpion might not be exposed, and wouldn't need to be immune. Not familiar enough with scorpion physiology to really know, but I do know that a common component of scorpion venom is phospholipase, an enzyme that can disrupt membranes. These enzymes are usually produced in an inactive form that must be activated by removing part of the enzyme. Other venom components may be stored in inactive forms as well.

Comment: Cross-posted on [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26952/what-will-happen-if-a-scorpion-pierces-itself).

Comment: I am sorry. I have deleted it on Skeptics.

Comment: If scorpions evolve by fighting each other, perhaps there is a kind of 'arms race' where the anti-venom of one scorpion is stronger than the other's sting, it will survive it...but if the sting of one is stronger than the others antivenom, it will win the fight , kill or stun it? Is this how scorpons have become more toxic over time?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zB5xiog7jk8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scorpions are immune to their own venom ([reference](http://animals.sandiegozoo.org/animals/scorpion)) as has been said in some studies as well ([reference](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/201/18/2625.full.pdf)) But some other studies and eye witness accounts have referred to the contrary.

> in an experiment a scorpion, Bulteus australis, was killed by an
>   injection of the same venom as its own ([reference](http://www.mocavo.com/Nature-a-Weekly-Illustrated-Journal-of-Science-July-Dec-1922-Volume-110/696683/328)).

So, it should be safe to say that there is a very low chance for a scorpion to be affected by its own venom. It is said that

> Mutations in the scorpion’s own membrane protein genes make the
>   arachnid immune to its own venom ([reference](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/scorpion-genome-decoded)).

A scorpion could die quickly if venom is injected into its brain (nerve ganglion). Larger species inject a higher amount of venom to overcome the smaller ones and should have specific neurotoxins if smaller scorpions are their prey to disable them ([reference](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=vQFEeohchVQC&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=scorpion%20immune%20to%20its%20own%20venom&source=bl&ots=pMdK7YvbMj&sig=fngLmrllpfxg56LHkbrVRA5YaT0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e3AKVaWQCpDluQT234DgAg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=scorpion%20immune%20to%20its%20own%20venom&f=false)).

Comment: Didn't know this one was answered +1. I tried, and failed :-) Haven't seen you around for a while!

Comment: @AliceD Busy with some paper writing and PhD applications.. hard to get into a decent funded PhD project these days so the effort continues.. :)